# Local polynomial regression: Why does the variance increase monotonically in the degree?

Tags: nonparametric, least-squares, polynomial, nonparametric-regression

How can I show that the variance of local polynomial regression is
increasing with the degree of the polynomial (Exercise 6.3 in Elements
of Statistical Learning, second edition)?

This question has been asked [before](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79719/how-to-show-the-variance-of-local-polynomial-regression-increases-with-degree) but the answer just states it follows easliy.

More precisely, we consider $y_{i}=f(x_{i})+\epsilon_{i}$ with $\epsilon_{i}$
being independent with standard deviation $\sigma.$

The estimator is given by

$$
\hat{f}(x_{0})=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & x_{0} & x_{0}^{2} & \dots & x_{0}^{d}\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
\alpha\\
\beta_{1}\\
\vdots\\
\beta_{d}
\end{array}\right)
$$
for $\alpha,\beta_{1},\dots,\beta_{d}$ solving the following weighted
least squares problem
$$
\min\left(y_{d}-\underbrace{\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & x_{1} & x_{1}^{2} & \dots & x_{1}^{d}\\
\vdots\\
1 &  &  &  & x_{n}^{d}
\end{array}\right)}_{X}\left(\begin{array}{c}
\alpha\\
\beta_{1}\\
\vdots\\
\beta_{d}
\end{array}\right)\right)^{t}W\left(y-\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & x_{1} & x_{1}^{2} & \dots & x_{1}^{d}\\
\vdots\\
1 &  &  &  & x_{n}^{d}
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
\alpha\\
\beta_{1}\\
\vdots\\
\beta_{d}
\end{array}\right)\right)
$$
for $W=\text{diag}\left(K(x_{0},x_{i})\right)_{i=1\dots n}$ with
$K$ being the regression kernel. The solution to the weighted least squares
problem can be written as
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\alpha & \beta_{1} & \dots & \beta_{d}\end{array}\right)=\left(X^{t}WX\right)^{-1}X^{t}WY.
$$
Thus, for $l(x_{0})=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & x_{0} & x_{0}^{2} & \dots & x_{0}^{d}\end{array}\right)\left(X^{t}WX\right)^{-1}X^{t}W$ we obtain
$$
\hat{f}(x_{0})=l(x_{0})Y
$$
implying that 
$$
\text{Var }\hat{f}(x_{0})=\sigma^{2}\left\Vert l(x_{0})\right\Vert ^{2}=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & x_{0} & x_{0}^{2} & \dots & x_{0}^{d}\end{array}\right)\left(X^{t}WX\right)^{-1}X^{t}W^{2}X\left(X^{t}WX\right)^{-1}\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & x_{0} & x_{0}^{2} & \dots & x_{0}^{d}\end{array}\right)^{t}.
$$
My approach: An induction using the formula for the inverse of a block
matrix but I did not succeed.

The paper [Multivariate Locally Weighted Least Squares Regression](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176325632)
by D. Ruppert and M. P. Wand derives an asymptotic expression for the variance for $n\rightarrow\infty$ in Theorem 4.1 but it is not clear that is increasing in the degree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the variance increases for every weighting matrix $W$, then this also holds true for $W=I$. Henceforth, I will use the notation of OLS. 
We have 
$$y=X\beta+u\textrm{,}
\qquad
\textrm{with}
\qquad
X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times k};\, y,u\in\mathbb{R}^{n};\, \beta\in\mathbb{R}^{k}$$
and with the standard assumptions. For a polynomial regression, let $\begin{pmatrix}x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}\end{pmatrix}^{T}=:x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be some vector, then we have 
$$X:=\begin{bmatrix}x^{0},x^{1},x^{2},\ldots,x^{k-1}\end{bmatrix}\textrm{,}$$
where exponenation is understood element-wise.

The OLS estimate for the polynomial weights is
$$\hat{\beta} := \left(X^{T}X\right)^{-1}X^{T}y\textrm{.}$$
For any $t\in\mathbb{R}$ we can set
$$z:=\begin{pmatrix}t^{0}\\t^{1}\\t^{2}\\\vdots\\t^{k-1}\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{k}\textrm{.}$$
An estimate of $y$ at $t$ is then given by $\hat{y}_{t}:=z^{T}\hat{\beta}$. 
For the variance of $\hat{y}_{t}$ w need to know its expected value:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[\hat{y}_{t}\right]
&=
\mathbb{E}\left[z^{T}\hat{\beta}\right]
=\mathbb{E}\left[z^{T}\left(X^{T}X\right)^{-1}X^{T}y\right]
\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[z^{T}\left(X^{T}X\right)^{-1}X^{T}X\beta + z^{T}\left(X^{T}X\right)^{-1}X^{T}u\right]
\\
&=z^{T}\beta + z^{T}\left(X^{T}X\right)^{-1}X^{T}\mathbb{E}\left[u\right] = z^{T}\beta
\end{align}
From this calculation we see that
$$\hat{y}_{t}-\mathbb{E}\left[\hat{y}_{t}\right] = z^{T}\left(X^{T}X\right)^{-1}X^{T}u\textrm{.}$$
Now we can calculate the variance of $\hat{y}_{t}$:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}\left[\hat{y}_{t}\right] &= \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\hat{y}_{t}-\mathbb{E}\left[\hat{y}_{t}\right]\right)\left(\hat{y}_{t}-\mathbb{E}\left[\hat{y}_{t}\right]\right)^{T}\right] 
\\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[\left(z^{T}\left(X^{T}X\right)^{-1}X^{T}u\right)\left(z^{T}\left(X^{T}X\right)^{-1}X^{T}u\right)^{T}\right]
\\
&= 
\mathbb{E}\left[\left(z^{T}\left(X^{T}X\right)^{-1}X^{T}u\right)\left(u^{T}X\left(X^{T}X\right)^{-1}z\right)\right]
\\
&= z^{T}\left(X^{T}X\right)^{-1}X^{T}\mathbb{E}\left[uu^{T}\right]X\left(X^{T}X\right)^{-1}z
\\
&=
\sigma^{2}z^{T}\left(X^{T}X\right)^{-1}z
\textrm{.}
\end{align}
If we increase $k\mapsto k+1$, we will have 
$$X_{*}:=\begin{bmatrix}x^{0},x^{1},x^{2},\ldots,x^{k-1},x^{k}\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times\left(k+1\right)}\textrm{,}$$
and therefore $\hat{\beta_{*}}\in\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$ and
$$z_{*}:=\begin{pmatrix}t^{0}\\t^{1}\\t^{2}\\\vdots\\t^{k-1}\\t^{k}\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{k+1}\textrm{.}$$
The variance of $\hat{y}_{t}^{*}$ is now a $\left(k+1\right)\times\left(k+1\right)$ matrix
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Var}\left[\hat{y}_{t}^{*}\right]=\sigma^{2}z_{*}^{T}\left(X_{*}^{T}X_{*}\right)^{-1}z_{*}\textrm{,}
\end{equation}
which we need to compare to the $k\times k$ matrix $\operatorname{Var}\left[\hat{y}_{t}\right]$.
Since we have inverses, the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Background) will help:
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}A & B\\C & D\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
= 
\begin{pmatrix} \left(A-B D^{-1} C \right)^{-1}  &   -\left(A-B D^{-1} C \right)^{-1} B D^{-1} \\ -D^{-1}C\left(A-B D^{-1} C \right)^{-1} & D^{-1}+ D^{-1} C \left(A-B D^{-1} C \right)^{-1} B D^{-1} \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Since we have
$$X_{*} := \begin{bmatrix}X,x^{k}\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$z_{*} := \begin{pmatrix}z\\t^{k}\end{pmatrix}$$
we can write with the abbreviation $q:=x^{k}$
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Var}\left[\hat{y}_{t}\right]
=
\sigma^{2}
\begin{pmatrix}z^{T},t^{k}\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}X^{T}X & X^{T}q \\ q^{T}X & q^{T}q\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}z\\t^{k}\end{pmatrix}
\textrm{.}
\end{equation}
We can now invert this block matrix using the aforementioned Schur complement and get
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}\left[\hat{y}_{t}\right]
&=
\sigma^{2}
\begin{pmatrix}z^{T},t^{k}\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \left(X^{T}X - X^{T}q \left(q^{T}q\right)^{-1} q^{T}X \right)^{-1}  & B_{*} \\ B_{*}^{T} & D_{*} \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}z\\t^{k}\end{pmatrix}
\\
&=
\sigma^{2}
\left(
z^{T}\left(X^{T}X - X^{T}q \left(q^{T}q\right)^{-1} q^{T}X \right)^{-1} z
+ t^{k}z^{T}B_{*} + t^{k}B_{*}^{T}z + t^{2k}D_{*}
\right)
\textrm{.}
\end{align}
The matrix $X^{T}q \left(q^{T}q\right)^{-1} q^{T}X$ is positive semi-definit, because it can be written as
$$X^{T}q \left(q^{T}q\right)^{-1} q^{T}X = \left(q^{T}q\right)^{-1}X^{T}qq^{T}X$$
and $qq^{T}$ is a rank $1$ matrix with the only non-vanishing eigen value equal to $q^{T}q$. The matrix $q \left(q^{T}q\right)^{-1} q^{T}$ is the projection on the subspace spanned by $q=x^{k}$, so $X^{T}X \succeq X^{T}q \left(q^{T}q\right)^{-1} q^{T}X$, i.e. the difference $X^{T}X - X^{T}q \left(q^{T}q\right)^{-1} q^{T}X$ is positive semi-definite. If we invert, the resulting matrix stays positive semi-definit, but it follows that
$$X^{T}X \succeq X^{T}q \left(q^{T}q\right)^{-1}X  
\implies
\left(X^{T}X\right)^{-1} \preceq \left(X^{T}q \left(q^{T}q\right)^{-1}X\right)^{-1}
$$
So in
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Var}\left[\hat{y}_{t}^{*}\right]
=
\sigma^{2}z^{T}\left(X^{T}X - X^{T}q \left(q^{T}q\right)^{-1} q^{T}X \right)^{-1} z
+ 2\sigma^{2}t^{k}z^{T}B_{*} + \sigma^{2}t^{2k}D_{*}
\textrm{.}
\end{equation}
We can calculate each of the terms and conclude that with increasing polynomial degree the variance is non-decreasing.

Comment: Dear Marco, thank you for your answer. I am bit confused about you saying that qqT is rank 1. With your notation q is just a scalar.

Comment: I adopted the convention that every vector $v$ is a column vector and every vector $v^{T}$ is a row vector. So $qq^{T}$ is a rank one matrix with only non-trivial eigenvalue $q^{T}q$. But you are right, when I first defined $x$, I did not write the transpose sign. I will add it in my answer.

Comment: I thought your arguments  would trivially generalise to the weighted case, but because of the $W^2$ in the expression for  $
\text{Var }\hat{f}(x_{0})$ it doesn’t. Do you have any advice on that?

Answer (score 0):

I'd share my incomplete solution, seems to work for $W=I$, but I failed to prove for a general matrix.

Different from Marco's answer, we can calculate from the estimator for a higher degree, say $d$, and treat the estimator for degree $d-1$ as a constrained least square estimator for degree $d$.

For simplicity, consider $W = I$ first. Let $\hat \beta$ be the least square estimator of degree $d$, i.e.,

$$
X = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_1 & \cdots & x_1^d\\
1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_2^d\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & x_n & \cdots & x_n^d
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and let $\hat\beta_c$ be the constrained least square estimator under the condition

$$
A\beta:=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 &\cdots & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\beta = 0
$$

In a word, $\hat\beta_c$ has the same dimension with $\hat\beta$, but the last element is 0.

By Lagrange multiplier, it can be shown that (such as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Constrained_estimation),

$$
\hat\beta_c = [I - (X^TX)^{-1}A^T(A(X^TX)^{-1}A^T)^{-1}A]\hat\beta\triangleq (I-\Delta)\hat\beta\,.
$$

Denote

$$
(X^TX)^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
* & * & \cdots & \sigma_{0d}\\
* & * & \cdots & \sigma_{1d}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\sigma_{d0} & \sigma_{d1} & \cdots & \sigma_{dd}
\end{bmatrix}_{(d+1)\times (d+1)}
$$

then $A(X^TX)^{-1}A^T=\sigma_{dd}$\, and

$$
A^T(A(X^TX)^{-1}A^T)^{-1}A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & 0\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \frac{1}{\sigma_{dd}}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where only the last diagonal element is nonzero, so only the last column of $\Delta$ is nonzero, with values

$$
\Delta_d = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\sigma_{0d}}{\sigma_{dd}} & \frac{\sigma_{1d}}{\sigma_{dd}} & \cdots & 1
\end{bmatrix}^T\,.
$$

Note that

$$
\newcommand\Var{\mathrm{Var}}
\newcommand\E{\mathrm{E}}
\begin{align}
\Var(\hat\beta_c) &= \E(\hat\beta_c-\beta_c)(\hat\beta_c-\beta_c)^T\\
&=(I-\Delta)\E(\hat\beta-\beta)(\hat\beta-\beta)^T(I-\Delta^T)\\
&=(I-\Delta)\Var(\hat\beta)(I-\Delta^T)
\end{align}
$$

then with new observation $z = [1, x, \cdots, x^d]$, and since $\Var(\hat\beta)=\sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1}$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\Var(z^T\hat\beta_c) &= z^T\Var(\hat\beta_c)z\\
&=z^T\Var(\hat\beta)z-2z^T\Delta\Var(\hat\beta)z + z^T\Delta\Var(\hat\beta)\Delta^Tz\\
&=\Var(z^T\hat\beta)-2\sigma^2z^T\Delta(X^TX)^{-1}z + \sigma^2z^T\Delta(X^TX)^{-1}\Delta^Tz
\end{align}\,,
$$

where

$$
\begin{align}
z^T\Delta(X^TX)^{-1}z &=
\begin{bmatrix}0,0,\ldots,\sum\limits_{k=0}^dx^k\dfrac{\sigma_{kd}}{\sigma_{dd}}\end{bmatrix}(X^TX)^{-1}z\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^dx^k\frac{\sigma_{kd}}{\sigma_{dd}}\begin{bmatrix}\sigma_{d0},\sigma_{d1},\ldots,\sigma_{dd}\end{bmatrix}z \\
&=\left(\sum_{k=0}^dx^k\frac{\sigma_{kd}}{\sigma_{dd}}\right)\cdot \left(\sum_{k=0}^dx^k\sigma_{kd}\right)\\
&=\left(\sum_{k=0}^dx^k\frac{\sigma_{kd}}{\sigma_{dd}}\right)^2\sigma_{dd}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
z^T\Delta(X^TX)^{-1}\Delta^Tz = \left(\sum_{k=0}^dx^k\frac{\sigma_{kd}}{\sigma_{dd}}\right)^2\sigma_{dd}
$$
thus,
$$
\Var(z^T\hat\beta_c) = \Var(z^T\hat\beta) - z^T\Delta(X^TX)^{-1}\Delta^Tz \le \Var(z^T\hat\beta)\,,
$$
which means the variance increases with the degree of the local polynomial.

For general weight matrix $W$, the constrained least square can be obtained easily via Lagrange multiplier,

$$
\hat\beta_c = [I - (X^TWX)^{-1}A^T(A(X^TWX)^{-1}A^T)^{-1}A]\hat\beta\triangleq (I-\Delta)\hat\beta\,,
$$

and continue the above procedure, but since

$$
\Var(\hat\beta) = (X^TWX)^{-1}(X^TW^2X)(X^TWX)^{-1}\,,
$$

is more complex than $W=I$, I failed to compare $2z^T\Delta\Var(\hat\beta)z$ and $z^T\Delta\Var(\hat\beta)\Delta^Tz$. I wish someone can give me some hints.