# Question about the answer to "Local polynomial regression: Why does the variance increase monotonically in the degree?"

Tags: regression, nonparametric, least-squares, nonparametric-regression

I appreciated Marco's [elegant answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139082/local-polynomial-regression-why-does-the-variance-increase-monotonically-in-the) explaining why the variance of a local polynomial regression increases monotonically in the degree. However, in the end of the proof, I find difficult to calculate each term in order to conclude the desired inequality.

If I pursue the proof from the last equation there, we can see that $$
\sigma^2 z^\top \left(X^\top X − X^\top q(q^\top q)^{−1}q^\top X\right)^{−1} z \geq \sigma^2 z^\top \left(X^\top X\right)^{−1}z = \mbox{Var}\left[\hat{y}_t\right],$$
by the arguments he mentioned. Then the following inequality holds for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$
$$\mbox{Var}[\hat{y}^∗_t] ≥ \mbox{Var}[\hat{y}_t]+ 2\sigma^2 t^k z^\top B_∗+\sigma^2 t^{2k} D_∗.$$
The conclusion is immediate if $2\sigma^2 t^k z^\top B_∗+\sigma^2 t^{2k} D_∗\geq 0$. Obviously $\sigma^2 t^{2k} D_∗≥0$ by construction of the Schur complement but I don't see how I can show that $2\sigma^2 t^k z^\top B_∗$ is positive for every $t$.

I don't see what I am missing.

Can anyone explain how to finish the proof?

Comment: can you please provide a link to the answer you seem to be referring to?

Comment: A question should not address an individual. I have reworded. Please check it still says what you intend.

Comment: I am also confused about Marco's answer, and then I tried a different solution. Details can be found in the original question ya wei (https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/171750/ya-wei), Local polynomial regression: Why does the variance increase monotonically in the degree?, URL (version: 2020-05-23): https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/468046