# Prove variance of locally weighted regression increases with degree

Tags: regression, variance, linear-algebra, polynomial, weighted-regression

I am interested in proving the following fact for locally weighted polynomial regression from *The Elements of Statistical Learning* by Hastie et. al.

> It can be shown that $||l(x_0)||$ increases with $d$...

The same fact is also mentioned in *Local Regression and Likelihood* by Loader:

> ... the influence function infl(x) increases as the degree of the
>   local polynomial increases.

Where $d$ is the degree of local polynomial and

$$ ||l(x_0)||^2 = b(x_0)^T(B^TWB)^{-1}B^TWW^TB(B^TWB)^{-1}b(x_0)$$
where $b(x)^T = (1, x, x^2, ..., x^{d-1})$, $B$ is the $N \times d$ regression matrix with *i*th row $b(x_i)^T$, and $W(x_0)$ is an $N \times N$ diagonal weight matrix.

[This question's](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139082/local-polynomial-regression-why-does-the-variance-increase-monotonically-in-the) accepted solution solves a related variance problem in the special case when $W = I_{N \times N}$, however this doesn't cover the more general case as it uses the fact that $I_{N \times N} \times I_{N \times N} = I_{N \times N}$ which is not the case for $W$.